# ng-repeat index in alphabetical format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have the `$index` outputting in an alphabetical format rather than numbered.

`<div ng-repeat="name in names">{{$index}}</div>`

Is that possible to do?

Comment: you could try `<div ng-repeat="name in names orderBy: 'name'">`

Comment: Do you mean $index [1, 2, 3,...] to [a, b, c,...] ?

Comment: @BrunoGomes `$index` starts from 0 and goes up right? I would like this to start at A and go up.

Comment: Why dont you style it in a list: ol {list-style-type: upper-latin}

Comment: @brunoGomes as that is not a way for formatting the data itself, all its doing is styling the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

Javascript:

```
// the alphabet    
$scope.alphabet['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

// get the index and return the letter of the alphabet
$scope.getLetter = function(index) {

  return $scope.alphabet[index];

};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">{{getLetter($index)}}</div>
```

**Edit** (thanks to @TheShalit & @patrick):

Javascript:

```
// get the index and return the letter of the alphabet
$scope.getLetter = function(index) {

  return String.fromCharCode(65+index);

};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">{{getLetter($index)}}</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cLto7mff/

Comment: You can use `String.fromCharCode(64 + index)` to get char without alphabet array

Comment: I would use `String.fromCharCode(65 + $index)` since the index is 0-based, otherwise the letters starts with '@'. You can see a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/cLto7mff/

Comment: That was what I found as the downfall to my solution, brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `orderBy` filter of angular

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy:'name'">{{name}}</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/632/)

Comment: i'm not looking to order by at all? I would just like the index to be alphabetical instead of numerical.

Comment: could you explain with example..so that i can create something which will work for you..

Comment: `A. Adam
B. John
C. Julie` rather than `1. Adam 2. John 3. Julie`

Comment: does your data is in `{'A':'1', 'B':'2',...}` this format

Comment: No it isn't + I was looking for a solution which would work for all different kinds of data.

Comment: And it wasn't me who downvote btw, I haven't got enough rep for that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77026/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-michaelwilson2013).

Comment: @downvoter it wasn't clear that he want data in this format`{'A':'1', 'B':'2',...}`  while I added an answer